# Define Router to use SSL by default

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a AWS ELB with default port 443 (SSL) and accessing the EC2 using port 80.

If I use `$this->Url->build()` or `Router::url()` always return url without https.

Exists a possibility to set `Router::url()` to use SSL by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to generate https urls:

```
router::url([
    'controller' => 'yourController', 
    'action' => 'yourAction',
    '_full' => true,
    '_ssl' => true
]);
```

Reference http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Routing.Router.html#_url

to set the default to ssl I think you will need to override the cake core and change the default _ssl setting to true  (vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\routing\Router.php) but I would not go that far